# Memento in Javascript

Tags: javascript, undo-redo, memento

I'm looking for a JavaScript implementation of the memento pattern (GoF) to be used in CRUD forms. In its basic level it will be enough to undo changes on inputs, but it would be great to use it with standard JS frameworks like YUI or Ext, to undo & redo grid actions ( new row, delete row etc.).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since I'm not seeing any code examples, here is a quick 'n Dirty implementation of undo for an EXT form:

```
var FormChangeHistory = function(){
    this.commands = [];
    this.index=-1;
}

FormChangeHistory.prototype.add = function(field, newValue, oldValue){
    //remove after current 
    if (this.index > -1 ) {
        this.commands = this.commands.slice(0,this.index+1)
    } else {
        this.commands = []
    }
    //add the new command
    this.commands.push({
        field:field,
        before:oldValue,
        after:newValue
    })
    ++this.index
}

FormChangeHistory.prototype.undo = function(){
    if (this.index == -1) return;
    var c = this.commands[this.index];
    c.field.setValue(c.before);
    --this.index
}

FormChangeHistory.prototype.redo = function(){
    if (this.index +1 == this.commands.length) return;
    ++this.index
    var c = this.commands[this.index];
    c.field.setValue(c.after);
}

Ext.onReady(function(){
    new Ext.Viewport({
        layout:"fit",
        items:[{    
            xtype:"form",
            id:"test_form",
            frame:true,
            changeHistory:new FormChangeHistory("test_form"),
            defaults:{
                listeners:{
                    change:function( field, newValue, oldValue){
                        var form = Ext.getCmp("test_form")
                        form.changeHistory.add(field, newValue, oldValue)
                    }   
                }
            },
            items:[{
                fieldLabel:"type some stuff",
                xtype:"textfield"
            },{
                fieldLabel:"then click in here",
                xtype:"textfield"
            }],
            buttons:[{
                text:"Undo",
                handler:function(){
                    var form = Ext.getCmp("test_form")
                    form.changeHistory.undo();
                }
            },{
                text:"Redo",
                handler:function(){
                    var form = Ext.getCmp("test_form")
                    form.changeHistory.redo();
                }
            }]
        }]
    })
});
```

Implementing this for an editable grid is a little trickier, but you should be able to make a GridChangeHistory that does the same thing and then call the add() function from EditorGrid's AfterEdit listener.

The "before" and "after" properties could be callback functions which allow you undo/redo any kind of command, but that would require more work when calling add()

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to undo/redo commands, I suggest using the [Command pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) instead.  [Here is a link to a tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/sharped.aspx); it's in C#, but it should be simple enough to follow for an OO programmer.